How to Display Time Labels at X-axis Correctly in R ggplot
I try to plot the data with R ggplot but the time label cannot display at x-axis correctly.   Any advice will be greatly appreciated.
Here is what the sample data looks like:
structure(list(activity = c("Running", "Running", "Running", 
"Running", "Running", "Running", "Running", "Running", "Running", 
"Running"), time = structure(c(-2209064400, -2209064100, -2209063800, 
-2209063500, -2209063200, -2209062900, -2209062600, -2209062300, 
-2209062000, -2209061700), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), level = c(0.0450582956975968, 0.049786810752437, 
0.049786810752437, 0.0409378662803991, 0.0373264654807176, 0.0373264654807176, 
0.0518442650051548, 0.0471157499503146, 0.0527766243609182, 0.0615719801782924
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

The data can be visualized in Excel correctly.

But I cannot plot the same data right in R. The time labels are not presented
appropriately and the data shape looks wrong as well.

Here are the R codes I use:
ggplot(df2, aes(x = time, y = activity)) + geom_density_ridges2()


You are using two different time scales so the plot will look different.

can you please give more details? what's the problem exactly and how to fix?  Thanks.

geom_density_ridges is the wrong function here. You are graphing the level of each activity in Excel. This is not the same as the density of observations, which is why the shapes are wrong, It seems likely you want aes(x = time, y = level) and use geom_line instead of geom_density_ridges. You can then facet by activity. You probably need to add scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%H:%M")  to your plot to change the labels on the x axis. We can't really give you exact code because you haven't provided a [mre] including data-as-text instead of images. dput(head(df, 10)) would help us.

Thanks Allan.  I just uploaded sample data-as-text with dput(head(df1, 10)).  Can you please run it to see what the problem is?   Really appreciated.

You need to use scale_x_datetime, with the argument date_labels = "%I:%M %p" to get the same output format as Excel.
However, geom_density_ridges is the wrong function here. You are graphing the level of each activity in Excel, not the density of measurements across the x axis, which is why the shapes are wrong.
Using an approximation of your data set as shown in the question with the same basic structure and names, we can reproduce your Excel plots in R as follows:
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(activity = factor(activity, c("Walking", "Running"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(time, level, color = activity)) + 
  geom_line(linewidth = 1) + 
  facet_wrap(activity ~ ., ncol = 1, scales = "free") +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "1 hour",
                   date_labels = "%I:%M %p") +
  scale_colour_manual(NULL, values = c("deepskyblue4", "orangered")) +
  labs(x = NULL) +
  theme_bw(16) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1, angle = 45),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"))



Thank you very much Allan. It works great. I learned a lot from it.
